# Is it any possible to convert analog phone to IP phone using Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, telephone

I need IP Phone for VOIP purpose. I have Raspberry PI and analog phone. Is there any possibility for interfacing analog phone with Raspberry PI.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. You could just remove everything from the phone and only use the microphone, speaker and optionally the buzzer and connect them to the RPi. Some of them might need an amplifier though. Is someone here going to tell you how to do that ? No so search around for projects connecting microphones and speakers to an RPi.

Comment: Given enough time, money and knowledge - yes. But it would be much easier to buy an Analogue Telephone Adaptor (ATA) .

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you need a 48Vdc source and emulate the CO functionality (Dial tone,Busy tone, ring back etc). An easier approach would be to use a headset and a SIP phone software on the RPi.

Comment: could you please tell detailed about CO functionality. I need to use individual handset instead of headphone.

Answer (score 1):

Given the low cost and extensive R&D skills to develop, it may be better to learn by RevEng and move on.  These are already avail, $15 cdn.

[image]